# Name that iconic character! #1

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

*This is part of the [Name That Iconic Character!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22Name+That+Iconic+Character%21%22+user%3A80017) series.*

Using the clues provided below, can you figure out what iconic character I'm thinking of?

---

Your clues:

```
BDAGA BDA BDAGDCBA
```

Answer format: `_____`

---

I'll add hints if nobody is able to make any progress. Good luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The character is

> Zelda

The letters `BDAGA BDA BDAGDCBA` are

> musical notes from the melody to the song "Rescued the Princess" from the soundtrack of the SNES game *The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past*. Here is a [timestamped link to the game's soundtrack](https://youtu.be/85u34SUh05Y?t=1678) where the melody can be heard at about the 28-minute mark.

Comment: That’s probably it and if right it makes it a very niche puzzle and like a stealth trivia question at best!

Answer (score 5):

The iconic character is…

> **SONIC**!

Reasons

> 1) If you look at the letters and the spacings on the clue you can superimpose **SONIC THE HEDGEHOG** on it!

> [image]

> 2) You are looking for a 5 letter answer!

> 3) Sonic is an iconic character

> 4) Iconic in the title if split in two lead **ic** and **onic** both of which are letter strings in S**onic**.

> 5) The letters are **musical notes** which also when played in a sequence make a nice melody which goes hand in hand with the name Sonic since the latter is also an adjective meaning ‘relating to the nature of sounds’ which makes it an apt adjective for it. They can be seen therefore as pointing to his name!!